# Fixed Button Postition in relative scrollable content

Tags: css

i have a really strange css positioning problem. What i need is a fixed button on the bottom of a centered div which is scrollable. On the Sceenshot you will see, how the result should look like. I tried with position:fixed. But than the button will be shown over the complete site. But it should be inside the div with a width of 100%.

I really how you can show me an example!

Kind regards and thanks to all supporters.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFhbM.png)

Comment: Please post the code you tried in your question.

Comment: Fixed position affects all document, not the parent div. If the div is always on bottom, maybe you can use an scroll event with Javascript. Another option is create another div under your scrollable div or use an absolute position on your button considering that the user need to read all scrollable div.

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this recently

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rtxxkjak/

It involves having an outer div and then an  inner div that holds that content you want to be scrollable. The button is then fixed to the bottom of the content div

Snippet: (height may be an issue)

```css
.top {
  height: 340px;
  width: 340px;
}

.container{
  background: red;
  overflow: scroll;
  max-height: 90%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#button{
  z-index: 4;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: white;
}

button {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  height: 10%;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<div class="top">

<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                
  </ul>
</div>
  <button id="button" type="submit">Submit</button>

</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the button needs to be Inside the scrollable div!